# Doctrine - How to access a User's active Address through the User entity when it can have one or more Addresses?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a User and Address entity. A user can have many Addresses, but only one of them can be marked as `active`.

I want the User entity to have a property that is $activeAddress which would contain an Address.  In other words, getActiveAddress() would return an Address object.

Is there a way to set up an annotation to do this similar to a one to one annotation?  This is essentially a one to one relationship as long as we are able to enforce a filter.

So for User with an id of 5:

SELECT * FROM address WHERE active = 1 AND user_id = 5 LIMIT 1;

This would always return the active address.  How do I set up my User entity to reflect this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the collection criteria API which allows you to transparently filter collections. Doctrine will trigger either a SQL query or filter the in memory association when it is already loaded.

```
public function getActiveAddress()
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("active", true))
        ->setMaxResults(1);

    $addresses = $this->addresses->matching($criteria);
    if ($addresses->count() == 1) {
        return $addresses->current();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This would work, but this looks like it would need to run a query for each User.  Wouldn't a JOIN of Address on User table be able to do this with one query?  Ex:  SELECT * FROM user JOIN address ON address.user_id = user.id WHERE address.active = 1;

Comment: This is exactly the query which would be executed by my solution. You have to implement this method in the user class, so the addresses collection will be bound to the actual user.